# Taper not working on beveled object

Tags: bevel

I have a line which is bevelled with a circle to make a cylinder. I want to taper it with the curve on the right side. When I choose the taper object to be the curve, the cylinder dissapears. How do I use the curve to taper the cylinder ?
[image]

The file is [available here](https://pasteall.org/media/b/1/b148b525f4bca6f813112d0238169b80.blend).

Comment: it should work, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: uploaded here : https://pasteall.org/media/b/1/b148b525f4bca6f813112d0238169b80.blend

Answer (score 1):

Apply rotation to both curves before, then you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the taper object and the curve itself.

First of all, like @Chris says, your curves have non applied rotations and those always tend to mess things up.

Another problem is that your modeled your taper object in the Z direction but Blender takes the taper value from the coordinates along the Y axis :

[image]

This is a screenshot from [the official documentation about the taper object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html) :

[image]

Look at what happens when I move one of the taper object's control points along the x axis :

[image]

With that said, your curves still responds to the taper in a funny way and I had real trouble trying to figure out how it was supposed to work so the best solution I found is to redo everything from the beginning **without rotating the curves or transforming them in Object Mode**. The steps are simple :

Add a Bezier Curve

[image]

Scaling everything by `0` on the Y axis, to get a cylinder

[image]

And add another Bezier for the taper object

[image]

You can now model your taper object but just remember that **only the positions of the curve's vertices on the local X and Y axis will be taken into account** :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mqbaka and Chris answers, once you've applied the taper rotation and aligned it with the X axis, it looks like you need to switch your curve handle type from *Vector* to *Automatic* or *Aligned* (select its vertices in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>V</kbd>)