# Usage of taper object

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, extrude

I'm learning about tapering objects watching [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR2-iEUgyVQ) and [reading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253122/taper-not-working-on-beveled-object) questions.
Still I have some issues understanding how it works.

[image]

Please, take a look at the attached blender file.

What I did:

1. created the "Path" curve
2. created the "Section" curve
3. created the "Taper" curve, duplicating the "Path" and moving on the X axis
4. applied all the transformations
5. set Section as Geometry > Bevel Object on the Path curve
6. set Taper as Geometry > Taper Object on the Path curve

Now, if I try to move any handle of the Taper curve on the X axis the extruded profile changes abruptly with no real control (just 1 pixel from shrinked to the original size).

My goal is to make the upper part thinner and the lower part fatter.

Actually, I would like also to change the cross-section along the path: the upper part should be close to the circle, while the bottom part larger on the X axis (like an ellipse). But I think I can easily achieve this second step just scaling the resulting tapered object.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ... Ha  OK can be closed as dupli ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Taper

Taper is 2D info ... your egg object takes radius (or size of profile object) from taper's distance on Y axis (X axis represents start/end of your "egg" curve.

[image]

Since Taper is controller, scale the "Section" object to 2m (I don't know why ... I would expect 1m like when *Geometry > Bevel > Round > Depth*), than distance of Taper's control points on Y axis corresponds to radius.

### No Taper

BTW for such shape you dont have to use a Taper ... you can just select control point and adjust *Radius* ...

[image]

... and instead of your "Section" you can use already mentioned *Geometry > Bevel > Round > Depth*

Instead of Subdivision modifier go to *Curve Data Propertie*s and increase **Resolution Preview**.

### Oval

To make bottom part oval profiled you can use **Lattice** modifier or **Mesh Deform** modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I'm going to study and try the last ones since I don't know them yet

Comment: Do you suggest to begin with a torus, then?

Comment: No, use your Bezier Circle, and instead your Profile and Taper objects use just parameters (all available) under Curve Data Properties.

Answer (score 2):

The taper object needs to be an open curve and only the distance to the origin on X and Y will be taken into account, not on the Z axis, so you should have a taper object that looks like that (note that for your main object I've changed the first point of the curve with the *Bsurfaces* addon > *N panel > Edit > Bsurfaces > Set First Points*):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in most tutorials they duplicate the path object - hence my confusion!